# Fixing latop screens

Tags: display, laptop

My laptop screen works fine sometimes, other times it goes blank. Is there a quick way to fix it? Probably some loose connection.

Comment: Take it down the repair shop?

Comment: Just a note: Laptop screens are notoriously expensive to replace if they indeed need to be replaced. If its an older laptop, it might be worth your money to buy a new laptop all together. However it sounds like a loose connection, take it to a repair shop.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to open up your laptop to fix any loose connections are game for that? 
There  could be a possibility that the card that connects the screen to the motherboard could be giving away.

I suggest you get it checked up at a shop if you are not too sure about taking the laptop apart.

Answer (score 1):

If it changes as you move it (ie, opening, closing or readjusting), it is most likely the signal cable. This is a relatively easy fix if it is the case, but can take some time and you will need to keep good track of the screws as you pull the laptop apart.

If it just does it on its own while you are using the laptop, it is more likely to be that your video card/processor is going out or the lighting element in your LCD is. Either way, this is not a good thing. The screen can be replaced, but is expensive and time consuming. If it is the video card/processor, it is most likely integrated into the motherboard and you'll have to replace the whole board, which is also expensive and time consuming.